# How to execute multiple proc in tcl scripting

Tags: parallel-processing, tcl

I have 4 proc in my tcl script. Each proc contain a while loop to wait for a task to be finished and to process the result files subsequently. My purpose now is to parallel this 4 process together instead of 1 by 1. Anyone has any idea?

Background:
The normal way before is I open 4 terminal in KDE/GNOME to execute the different tasks. 4 different tasks actually running together.

Comment: Are the procedures CPU-bound, disk-bound or (other) IO-bound?

Comment: @Donal Fellows , I'm submitting the job to some kind of server. Hence i'm thinking to submit them in parallel. But at the same time, i need to wait for the result come back to proceed next operation.

Answer (score 1):

Tcl threads can do the job just fine: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/thread.htm

Of course you may just leave everything as it is and run your scripts in the background within one terminal, if that's what you are looking for, e.g.

```
script1.tcl &
script2.tcl &
```

Answer (score -1):

threading is better option for this scenario and it gives better control for your subprocess. You refer the following link for simple example : https://www.activestate.com/blog/2016/09/threads-done-right-tcl